# Android images backup to the Cloud

Tags: backup, images, dropbox, cloud

Is there a way to backup all images of my Android, something like Dropbox, but for all images of gallery, not only camera and screenshots? But for monitor other folders, created by other apps too, like 'WhatsApp images' or 'Messenger'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very flexible solution for this issue is offered by [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync-lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite): this app not only allows you to specify which local folders should be synchronized with which remote ones, but also supports a ton of different services, including Dropbox, FTP/SFTP/FTPS, Google Drive/Docs, WebDAV, Ubuntu One, and a bunch of others. I use it myself for Dropbox and SFTP, and am very satisfied (switched to the payed version quite soon after having tried it).

Comment: I'm trying some apps. I already had DropSync, I think FolderSync can do the same thing but with more services. And I think it works the way I want. DropSync is enough to DropBox, but I think for others, I'll need FolderSync.

Comment: Agreed, to my knowledge that's true. But *FolderSync* also gives you more flexibility than *DropSync* (e.g. scheduled syncs, *Tasker* support, and more). // Please don't forget to come back and accept the solution chosen by clicking the checkmark next to the corresponding answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of apps that will allow you to backup images to the cloud in addition to Dropbox. Some are more "aggressive" than others.

- [Google+ Auto-Backup](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509)
- [Copy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.copy)
- [Carbonite Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carbonite.android)
- [BitTorrent® Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bittorrent.sync)
- more...

Comment: But, these apps, allow me to choose the folders or just camera uploads like Dropbox? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, some are more aggressive about grabbing new images in various places. Except for G+ and Dropbox I haven't spent a lot of time with any of them. You'll probably just want to install and see how it works for you.

Comment: If you want to sync specific folders, take a look at [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync-lite/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). Works with multiple services, including Dropbox.

Comment: @Izzy: That seems like it should be an answer.

Comment: OK, done so. Thought it rather an addition to your answer, but it also can do "stand-alone" :)

Comment: Copy doesn't allow you to choose the folder, only camera uploads, probably DCIM directory. The same with G+ Auto-Backup. BitTorrent is not cloud but should work, I didn't try. Carbonite seems to do too much things, didn't try either.

Comment: Well, my point wasn't that these apps let you choose the folders, but rather that some are more aggressive in where they look for images to back up.

Answer (score 1):

There's some options that I found after trying and researching:

- MyShoeBox: this seems to be the most "dedicated" app for this thing, but there are limitations like the max size of image and resolution (free plans).
- Cloudii: like FolderSync, but free just for a couple of days, and there's a option to automatically send camera photos, is easy to use.
- DropSync: does the same, but only for Dropbox, and you can choose which folders, or file type to filter, but just in a excluding way.
- FlickrUploader: maybe not the best option because of the Flickr terms about usage of the service.

But I think, the most advanced option is FolderSync, the only that can filter files by type (not images only) and features advanced options.